# Justify Content for different break points Bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

How can I justify content of a column for different breakpoints. For example, I want the following email text to be justified to the end for > medium columns but justified to the centre for smaller columns. Looking for an elegant solution.

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              Email
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you [read the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/text/)? Do you mean aligning text within the column, or the column within the row?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To position the content of the column div you can use the responsive versions of justify-content-* class with d-flex

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-md-end justify-content-center">
      Email
    </div>
</div>
```

Just add the classes d-flex to display flex  and justify-content-md-end to align at the end of the column for display md and upwards and justify-content-center
to align to center for display xs and upwards.

[Demo](https://www.bootply.com/rJmtQU8krl)

Comment: man... you are totally right. #@#$ just missed that in the documentation. u got your points. ;)

Comment: Happy to help. Thanks for accepting the answer.